# Cómo saber por cuál de los 2 canales llegan los mensajes [WebRTC]

Tags: javascript, async-await

Estoy tratando de identificar por cuál de los dos canales llegó un mensaje, pero no sé cómo puedo diferenciarlos.

¿Cómo podría lograr hacerlo?

```js
let channel = null;
let channel2 = null;

channel = connection.createDataChannel('data');
channel2 = connection.createDataChannel('data2');


connection.ondatachannel = (event) => {

// Estoy seguro de que es aquí, pero no sé cómo asignar según cada event.channel .
channel = event.channel;
channel2 = event.channel;


// Independientemente de si se escribe channel o channel2, los mensajes se mezclan.

channel.onmessage = (event) => {}
channel2.onmessage = (event) => {}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes diferenciar entre los dos canales de datos utilizando la propiedad label de cada uno. Cada canal de datos tiene una propiedad label que identifica de manera única el canal.

En tu código, puedes usar la propiedad label para asignar los eventos a cada canal de datos. Por ejemplo:

```
connection.ondatachannel = (event) => {
  const channel = event.channel;

  if (channel.label === 'data') {
    channel.onmessage = (event) => {
      // Este código se ejecutará cuando se reciba un mensaje en el canal 'data'.
    }
  } else if (channel.label === 'data2') {
    channel.onmessage = (event) => {
      // Este código se ejecutará cuando se reciba un mensaje en el canal 'data2'.
    }
  }
}
```

También puedes usar una estructura de datos como un objeto para almacenar los diferentes canales de datos y acceder a ellos de manera más fácil:

```
const dataChannels = {};

connection.ondatachannel = (event) => {
  const channel = event.channel;
  dataChannels[channel.label] = channel;
}

// Para acceder a un canal de datos en particular:
const dataChannel = dataChannels['data'];

dataChannel.onmessage = (event) => {
  // Este código se ejecutará cuando se reciba un mensaje en el canal 'data'.
}
```